# adicionar linha em branco numa list

Tags: c#, classes

tenho uma list já com dados e estou querendo que a cada 3 linha adicione uma linha em branco nessa list. Para depois passar para um grid. Como consigo fazer isso? Por enquanto o código está assim:

```
        anoanterior = Convert.ToString(fano);
        mesanterior = Convert.ToString(fmes);
        TAB_F_TABELAS_DAL d = new TAB_F_TABELAS_DAL();
        var dados = d.RetornaCronograma(anotual+mesatual, 
        anoanterior+mesanterior);   
        CT01_Array.DataSource = dados;
        CT01_Array.DataBind();
```

código na classe:

```
        List<eCT01> lst = new List<eCT01>();
        OpenConnection();
        using (Cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, Con))
        {
            Cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                eCT01 l = new eCT01();


                l.CICLO = dr["CICLO"].ToString();
                if(dr["MEDICAOMES"].ToString().Length == 5) { 
                 l.MEDICAO = "0" + dr["MEDICAOMES"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    l.MEDICAO = dr["MEDICAOMES"].ToString();
                }
                l.DT_BLOQ_CICLO = dr["DT_BLOQ_CICLO"].ToString();
                l.DT_LEITURA_HD = dr["DT_LEITURA_HD"].ToString();
                l.DT_ENT_LEITUR = dr["DT_ENT_LEITUR"].ToString();
                l.DT_EMIS_CT_BLOQ = dr["DT_EMIS_CT_BLOQ"].ToString();
                l.DT_ENT_CT_BLOQ = dr["DT_ENT_CT_BLOQ"].ToString();
                l.DT_VENC_OPC1 = dr["DT_VENC_OPC1"].ToString();
                l.DT_VENC_OPC2 = dr["DT_VENC_OPC2"].ToString();
                l.DT_VENC_OPC3 = dr["DT_VENC_OPC3"].ToString();
                l.DT_VENC_OPC4 = dr["DT_VENC_OPC4"].ToString();
                l.DT_VENC_OPC5 = dr["DT_VENC_OPC5"].ToString();
                l.DT_VENC_OPC6 = dr["DT_VENC_OPC6"].ToString();
                l.VLR_M3 = dr["VLR_M3"].ToString();
                l.VLR_M3_SEM_ESG = dr["VLR_M3_SEM_ESG"].ToString();
                l.VLR_M3_COM_ESG = dr["VLR_M3_COM_ESG"].ToString();
                l.VLR_TARIFA_SOCIAL = dr["VLR_TARIFA_SOCIAL"].ToString();
                l.PERC_REC_HIDRICOS = dr["PERC_REC_HIDRICOS"].ToString();
                l.PERC_TX_REGULACAO = dr["DT_ENT_LEITUR"].ToString();

                lst.Add(l);
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        CloseConnection();
        #endregion

        return lst;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael Veloso, você pode fazer um "mod" que em C# é o símbolo do "%" dessa forma:

```
eCT01 lx = new eCT01();
if(num % 3 == 0) lst.Add(lx);
```

... mas vai precisar de um contador "num" para saber em que linha você está.

Comment: Observe que `lst` é tipado dessa forma não é possível adicionar um valor que não seja do mesmo tipo da `List`.

Comment: @davidterra , e se passar um valor em branco? Dessa forma: "eCT01 lx = new eCT01();"

Comment: O problema de fazer assim, é que acabo pulando uma linha de dados. por conta desse "while" tipo ele lê e em vez de adicionar uma linha de dados ele adiciona uma linha em branco e já vai para a próxima linha.

Comment: @rafael-veloso , mas não tem como você fazer depois do "lst.Add(l);"?

Comment: Pessoal, consegui resolver!! Muito obrigado! Desculpe a demora da resposta